# VHDL Adding and two 8 bits registers in Simple 8bit Processor

Tags: overflow, vhdl, cpu, processor, 8-bit

I need to create a simple 8-bit processor that will add and subtract two registers. The result of addition and subtraction must be saved in register A. Data in registers A and B should be entered using the D_IN input.
Then I send register A to the D_OUT output.
Unfortunately, when I try to add these two registers together, I get the error "UUUUUUUU"

Thats my vhdl code

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    11:43:43 05/27/2020 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    projekt - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity projekt is
Port (
    S  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0); 
     D_IN : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
     D_OUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
    A_Out   : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
    C : out std_logic
    );
end projekt;

architecture Behavioral of projekt is

signal tmp: std_logic_vector (8 downto 0);
signal A : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal B : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);


begin
process(A,B,S,D_IN) is
begin
case(S) is
  when "0000" => 
  A <= A+B;
  when "0001" => 
  A <= A-B;
  when "0010" => 
  A <= D_IN; 
  when "0011" => 
  B <= D_IN; 
  when "0100" => 
  B <= A;
  when "0101" => 
  A <= B;
  when "0110" => 
  D_OUT <= A;
  when others =>

 end case;
 end process;

 tmp <= ('0' & A) + ('0' & B);
 C <= tmp(8);

end Behavioral;
```

And thats my testbench

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer:
--
-- Create Date:   11:58:50 05/27/2020
-- Design Name:   
-- Module Name:   /home/ise/projekt/projektTB.vhd
-- Project Name:  projekt
-- Target Device:  
-- Tool versions:  
-- Description:   
-- 
-- VHDL Test Bench Created by ISE for module: projekt
-- 
-- Dependencies:
-- 
-- Revision:
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments:
--
-- Notes: 
-- This testbench has been automatically generated using types std_logic and
-- std_logic_vector for the ports of the unit under test.  Xilinx recommends
-- that these types always be used for the top-level I/O of a design in order
-- to guarantee that the testbench will bind correctly to the post-implementation 
-- simulation model.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY projektTB IS
END projektTB;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF projektTB IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT projekt
    PORT(
         S : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         D_IN : IN  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         D_OUT : OUT  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         A_Out : OUT  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         C : OUT  std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal A : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal B : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal S : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal D_IN : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    --Outputs
   signal A_Out : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal D_OUT : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal C : std_logic;
   -- No clocks detected in port list. Replace <clock> below with 
   -- appropriate port name 

   constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: projekt PORT MAP (
          S => S,
          D_IN => D_IN,
          D_OUT => D_OUT,
          A_Out => A_Out,
          C => C
        );



   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
      D_IN <= "00000001";
        S <= "0010";
        wait for 100 ns;
        D_IN <= "00000001";
        S <= "0011";
        wait for 100 ns;
        S <= "0000";
        wait for 100 ns;
        S <= "0110";




      -- insert stimulus here 

      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

When im doing that (result of adding A+B in D_Out, not in A) everything is good. But i need this in A .

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    11:43:43 05/27/2020 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    projekt - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity projekt is
Port (
    S  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0); 
     D_IN : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
     D_OUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
    C : out std_logic
    );
end projekt;

architecture Behavioral of projekt is

signal tmp: std_logic_vector (8 downto 0);
signal A : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal B : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal test : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
signal tmpA : integer;
signal tmpB : integer;
signal tmpSum : integer;



begin
process(A,B,S,D_IN,tmpA,tmpB,tmpSum) is
begin
case(S) is
  when "0000" => 



D_OUT <= A+B;


  when "0001" => 

 D_OUT <= A-B;

  when "0010" => 
  A <= D_IN; 
  when "0011" => 
  B <= D_IN; 
  when "0100" => 
  B <= A;
  when "0101" => 
  A <= B;
  when "0110" => 
  D_OUT <= A;
  when others =>

 end case;
 end process;

 tmp <= ('0' & A) + ('0' & B);
 C <= tmp(8);

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: "UUUUUUUU" is not an error. I think the real problem when you try to do your addition is that your process has `A` in its sensitivity list and performs the assignment `A <= A+B`. Therefore, any time `A` changes, it causes the process to execute, which causes `A` to change, which causes the process to execute, which causes `A` to change....... so you have an infinite loop. Doesn't your processor have a clock?

Comment: This project is supposed to be  a simple 8-bit one, without using a clock. 
Do you think that if I used a temporary variable to do the calculations, this would solve the problem?

Comment: I would encourage you to think more about what hardware you are trying to describe. If you were writing software, then it would be a good idea to think about temporary variables. However, you're actually writing hardware. What hardware would you want that temporary variable to infer? You need some kind of memory element to record the numbers you input via D_IN. Without a clock, you can't use clocked flip-flops, but I guess you could infer asynchronous latches. These have different nets (wires) on the input and output. So I suggest you have one signal for the input and one for the output.

Comment: A won't have an event without assigning a different value to at least one subelement. With 'U's this explains why you're not getting a message about hitting a maximum number of delta cycles. You never load B with a value from A or D_IN in the test bench (S = "0011" or S = "1000"). There are also executions of the process that don't update signals meaning you can have latches when synthesized.  Thinking hardware can be a little involved. The reason D_OUT has all 'U's is that it is never assigned.

Comment: Both `A` and `B` are assigned with "00000001" (see `S <= "0011";` in the testbench). So adding 1 will always assign a different value to `A`. I have run the testbench in Modelsim and get *Error (suppressible): (vsim-3601) Iteration limit 5000 reached at time 200 ns*. This is the real error that Boniek should be looking at. The warning about A_Out having no driver and contributing "UUUUUUUU" is just noise.

Comment: When im doing that (result of adding  A+B in D_Out, not in A) everything  is good. But i need this in A . Check my new code in my post update.